# Wordpress deployed through wp-deploy not accessible (but can access admin/dashboard)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, capistrano

I'm using [wp-deploy](https://github.com/Mixd/wp-deploy) to deploy wordpress to my server. The deployment is successful. The database has all the required tables.

I'm able to access the admin page through: `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php`. Using the password supplied at the end of the deploy script, I'm also able to login and interact with the dashboard.

The problem is, I'm not able to access the wordpress homepage: `http://example.com`. It's just the 'white screen of death'. There's nothing in the apache error log. The apache access log has this entry when I visit the homepage:

`"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/39.0.2171.65 Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36"`

Normally when wordpress is extracted and put into `/var/www/html`, the `index.php`, `.htaccess`, and `wp-config.php` files would be along with all the other files in one `wordpress` folder. But `wp-deploy` has deployed to a slightly different structure since it uses capistrano(v3). Wordpress is deployed now into `/var/www/html/blog/current`. And within the `current` folder, there's only `index.php`, `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php`. Remaining files are present within another folder `wordpress`.

As per `wp-deploy`'s suggestion, I've made the DocumentRoot of apache point to the `current` folder. Here's the relevant Apache VirtualHost lines:

```
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/current
```

And here's the `WP_HOME`, `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_CONTENT_URL` from `wp-config.php` (This was autogenerated based on `stage_url` setting I gave in the deploy script. The value I gave was `http://example.com`):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/wordpress');

define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/content');
```

Also there's a `content` folder within `/var/www/html/blog/current`. It has these directories - plugins, themes, uploads. I think the `WP_CONTENT_URL` above refers to that.

`wp-deploy` has generated a `.htaccess` file in the `current` folder. [Here it is](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7f3f94cac461a0f3f96f). I tried deleting it and accessing the site, but no luck still.

Since I'm not much aware of php or apache, could anyone please clarify any mistakes I'm doing here?

PS: I have 2 DNS A records. '@' and 'blog' both pointing to my server's ip.

Comment: Just try going to admin/permalinks and just save again, no need to change anything. That will re-create the wp lines in your .htacess, and might fix things.

Comment: @GavinSimpson No, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was.. there was nothing present within the `themes` folder. The default theme files were present in the `wordpress/wp-content/themes` folder. But `wp-deploy` has modified the WP_CONTENT_URL in the `wp-config.php` file to a different folder outside of the `wordpress` folder. And it only had empty dirs for plugins and themes.

Once I copied the files into the new content folder, the site was up.